# Object Expected error in IE7, works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I have a site using Google Maps v3 api and some javascript to show information on a site I am building. The site works great in all browsers, even IE8. But in IE7, I get an Object Expected error on line 34 (initialize_trip function call I am guessing). I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error.

The page itself is here:

http://apt4b.com/test/trips/mountain-west.php

The js file that I believe is failing is here:

http://apt4b.com/test/js/controller.js

calling the initialize_map function located here:

http://apt4b.com/test/js/map_config.js

Thanks all!

Comment: Heh...the world would be a lot better off with IE.

Comment: @Inspire48.. assuming you meant without

Answer (score 5):

In you initialisation file (map_config.js), you have a lot of unneccessary trailling commas.

While most browsers will be permisive and ignore that, it is notorious for breaking IE.

E.g.

```
{
            featureType: "water",
            elementType: "all",
            stylers: [
                { hue: "#335a93" },
                { lightness: -20 },  // <-- Here, bad.
            ]
        }
```

Basically IE7 is probably ignoring the entire config file as bad syntax.

Haven't tried but I reckon that'll fix your problem.

**Edit:** The problematic spots are pretty obvious if you run it through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Comment: Yes, IE7 is not tolerant to the extra commas.

Comment: Ben, I tried the lint and cleared out the comma warnings, but still giving me the error. Any thoughts?

Comment: The errror appears on line 318 now. probably a different problem

Comment: you still have trailing comas in other places in your file (stopover: true,)

Comment: Thanks Ben! Who would have thought that IE7 would make me write better js. Got almost all of the it approved through jslint and the site works great now in IE7. Cheers.